# Is it possible to use conditions like if or case statement to add a value?

Tags: php, syntax, conditional-statements

I am trying to use if or case statement to get a certain value ready for import in my db.
currently the code is :

```
'price' => ((float)$this->data['nett-price'] + 1.30),
```

the nett-price is imported with a file and the 1.30 is a static value needed for all items.

Now I would like to have this to have added a certain price when a condition is met:

```
if (in_array($this->data['diameter'], array(
            10,
            11,
            12,
            13,
            14,
            15)))
            return '2.20';
        if (in_array($this->data['diameter'], array(16, 17)))
            return '4.40';
        return '2.20';
    }
```

then it should also check like:

```
if (in_array($this->data['width'], array(
            150,
            155,
            160,
            165)))
            return '2.20';
        if (in_array($this->data['diameter'], array(255, 260)))
            return '4.40';
        return '2.20';
    }
```

So in short I want to have the first code to be checked if it meets a first condition, then also check if it meets a second condition. Then it should add (only once) a value for the different conditions....

Hope I have explained it well enough as a beginner.

Comment: "Then it should at (only once) a value for the different conditions...." This sentence threw me off a little, maybe a typo?

Comment: sorry at should have been add.....the purpose is to add a shipping price value, so it is included in the price shown on the webpage, not as a seperate value. we have the nett-price + 1.30 and then it should check if it has a certain "weight" and "size" to determine the value added for shipping (which can be 2.20 or 4.40).

Answer (score 0):

if I understood correctly, all you need is using the AND `&&` between the condition and arrange them, because the `and` will not evaluate the second condition if the first one is not correct, in other words:

```
if( condition1 && condition2) {
    perform requested operation
}
```

plus one note, your example has 2.20 returned in the first condition and as a default value, but at the same time the 4.40 is the only conditional value, so we can make the code way better by just testing for the 4.40 value:

```
$addedValue = 0;
if (in_array($this->data['diameter'], array(16, 17)) || in_array($this->data['width'], array(255, 260)))
        $addedValue = 4.40;
else $addedValue = 2.20;
```

now you can do `'price' => ((float)$this->data['nett-price'] + 1.30 + $addedValue)`

Comment: ok i think i understand the way i should address the conditions,  but how do i get the result in: 'price' => ((float)$this->data['nett-price'] + 1.30),  and the it is not always a first condition also needs to be in the second condition. Like it can be 16 in the first but the second condition is not met, but still it should return 4.40 (sorry for all the questions).

Comment: check my updated answer and let me know if this is what you mean

Comment: Hi Labib, i cant seem to figure it out. can i give you a pm/email?